# generate empty/generic rows based on counts from different table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to generate something like this using postgres, from some arbitrary criteria:

Original table (t1):

```
type | count
------------
  1  |  2
  2  |  3
  3  |  1
```

Generated table:

```
type_1 | type_2 | type_3
------------------------
 true  |  null  | null
 true  |  null  | null
 null  |  true  | null
 null  |  true  | null
 null  |  true  | null
 null  |  null  | true
```

Answer (score 0):

The following basically accomplishes what you want:

```
with x as (
      select 1 as type, 2 as cnt union all
      select 2, 3 union all
      select 3, 1
     ) 
select x.type = 1, x.type = 2, x.type = 3
from x, lateral
     generate_series(1, x.cnt);
```

This produces `false` instead of `NULL`, but more complicated `case` expressions can easily solve that.